# Multiple parallel image-encoders in pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch

I have an image encoder which can generate output features. I want to split my image into several patches (around *16*) and feed each patch to a separate image encoder (the parameters for each encoder are different).
Initially, it's like:

`Input -> Encoder -> Output`

I want to change it like this:

```
patch-input1 -> Encoder1 -> output1
patch-input2 -> Encoder2 -> output2
...
patch-inputN -> EncoderN -> outputN
```

I'm using `nn.Module` to create the model class. The number of patches `N` is not fixed and is determined during the initialisation of the model so I wanted to use the list of objects (in `__init__()` function) to create multiple instances of the same encoder and call them over each part-input in a loop in the forward function.

When I run inference on a sample input, it doesn't show any error and I print out the number of trainable parameters using **torchsummary** module.
The problem is I do not see the parameters corresponding to the encoders in the number of parameters. More specifically in the single encoder pipeline there are around one million parameters and in the multiple encoder pipeline, params there are only around *200* thousand. The later's summary doesn't even show the description of various layers in the encoder.

A code snippet of my implementation would look like this:

```
class Patch(nn.Module):
   '''
   takes image tensor input
   returns a list of patch tensors
   '''
class Encoder(nn.Module):
   '''
   definition of the encoder
   '''
class Model(nn.Module):
   def __init__(self, patches=10, *kwargs):
      super().__init__()
      self.patch = Patch()
      self.enc = []
      for i in range(patches):
         enc.append(Encoder())
   def forward(self, x):
      '''
      patches is a list of tensors formed using an image 
      tensor
      '''
      patches = self.patch(x)
      output = []
      for i in range(patches):
         output.append(self.enc[i](patch[i]))
      output_feats = torch.cat(output, dim=0)
```

Is there a better way to implement parallel encoders? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: @Ivan added a snippet of how the code is structured

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a [`nn.ModuleList`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.ModuleList.html) in order to properly register the list of `Patch` modules inside `Model` [`nn.Module`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html):

```
class Model(nn.Module):
   def __init__(self, patches=10, *kwargs):
      super().__init__()
      self.patch = Patch()
      enc = []
      for i in range(patches):
         enc.append(Encoder())
      self.enc = nn.ModuleList(enc)
```

In a slightly refactored form:

```
class Model(nn.Module):
   def __init__(self, patches=10, *kwargs):
      super().__init__()
      self.patch = Patch()
      self.enc = nn.ModuleList(Encoder() for _ in range(patches))

   def forward(self, x):
      patches = self.patch(x)
      output_feats = torch.cat([enc(patch) for enc, patch in zip(self.enc, patches])
```

Comment: Thanks! I question, should it be self.patch in zip() function or patches? As the later is the list of patches, former is just an object to call the forward function to patch an image

Comment: Thanks for the help! This solution worked for me and accepted your answer, checked the green tick on the left ;)